# How to delete photo from Snapmatic?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

How to delete photo from Snapmatic ?

Photos I shoot in-game are automatically uploaded to Social Club's Snapmatic section, but I want to remove some of them.

Is there a delete button ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In game, if you press start you should be able to find a gallery tab where you can delete the photos using triangle/Y (PS3/360).  Note that you have to wait for all of the thumbnails to load before the delete option will be available.  I don't think you can remove them directly from the social club website.